# Notification builder instructions not working

Tags: android, notifications

I am creating a notification using some of the methods provided by `NotificationBuilder`.

I am testing it in real device and, from the following code, **none of the methods that I am marking with `--->` seems to be working:**

```
long[] vibratePattern = new long[] {
                500, 1000,
                500, 1000};


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "my_channel01");
        notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        ---> notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.testProfilePic));
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        ---> notificationBuilder.setColor(Color.parseColor("#aa0000"));
        ---> notificationBuilder.setVibrate(vibratePattern);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
```

So, in words, there is no vibration, no large icon and no background color.

Answer (score 0):

Try do this :

```
private static long[] vibratePattern = {500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500};
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.change_after_sync))
                .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(buildNotificationAfterSynchronizeText(dataResponse, context)))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setLargeIcon(Largeicon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(vibratePattern)
                .setLights(Color.GREEN, 2000, 2000)
                .build();
```

Comment: thanks I will try, what is your "LargeIcon" in method `setLargeIcon`??

Comment: nop still not working and I also get a bunch of deprecated methods in your code `Notification.Builder`, `setSound` `setVibrate` and `setLights`